# proving roots of equation $x^2+x+4f=0$ are real.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a,b,c$ be three positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=1$. Let $f=\min(a^3+a^2bc, b^3+ab^2c,c^3+abc^2)$. Prove that the roots of the equation $x^2+x+4f=0$ are real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to symmetry we may assume wlog $a\le b\le c$ (and especially, $a\le \frac13$).
Then $a^3\le b^3\le c^3$ and $a\cdot abc\le b\cdot abc\le c\cdot abc$, hence $f=a^3+a^2bc$. By the AM-GM inequality, $bc\le \frac14(b+c)^2=\frac14(1-a)^2$ (with equality if $b=c=\frac{1-a}2$), so 
$$4f\le 4a^3+a^2(1-a)^2=a^2(1+a)^2\le \frac{16}{81}.$$
The the discrimiant $D=1-16f$ of $x^2+x+4f$ is 
$$D\ge1-\frac{64}{81}=\frac{17}{81}>0$$
and hence $x^2+x+4f$ has two real roots.